# Why can't we declare private local inner class inside a method?

Tags: java, class

```
class outer
{
    public void outerfunction()
    {

        private class inner // Line-1
        {
                public void showinner()
                {
                    System.out.println("I am in Inner Class");

                }

        }

    }
}
```

Line-1 : This Line gives error.

I know if I write abstract or Final for class inner. then,it is fine. Why class inner can't be private ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `private` class is visible to all the methods and nested classes in the same file. Normally you would think of private as narrowing the scope of use, but in this case using `private` you are *broadening* the scope of where is the class is visible in a way Java doesn't support.

Making the method private is the same as doing this

```
class outer {
      private class inner { // Line-1
          public void showinner() {
              System.out.println("I am in Inner Class");    
          }
      }

      public void outerfunction() {    

     }
}
```

Which looks fine until you consider that a nested class can use the values in it's outer context.

```
class outer {
    public void printInner() {
        // accessible in the same .java file because we made it private
        inner i = new inner();
        i.showInner(); // what should `x` be?
    }

    public void outerfunction(final int x) {    
         private class inner { // Line-1
              public void showinner() {
                  System.out.println("I am in Inner Class, x= " + x);    
              }
          }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain bit more ? Thanks !

Comment: @ShashankJain method local classes in a method are only visible to that method, not everything in the same file as `private` nested classed are.

Comment: Then why Final is allowed ?

Comment: `final` is more restrictive.  It means it cannot be sub-classed.

Comment: final makes it non-inheritable

Comment: @ShashankJain  a `private class` in a method can only be implemented if the out scope is not used, in which case you can just move the class to be not method-local. I have added an example.